# Why my code is not working?

Tags: python, tkinter

New to tkinter, but as of now, I don't know why my code keeps returning Failed instead of passed.

```
import tkinter as tk

class GUI(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self)
        self.entry = tk.Entry(self)
        self.user_Label = tk.Label(self, text="Username")
        self.pass_entry = tk.Entry(self)
        self.pass_Label = tk.Label(self, text="Password")
        self.login = tk.Button(self, text="Login", foreground="black", command=self.on_button)

        #Packing
        self.user_Label.pack()
        self.entry.pack()
        self.pass_Label.pack()
        self.pass_entry.pack()
        self.login.pack()

    def on_button(self):
        if self.entry and self.pass_entry == "hello":
            print("passed")
        else:
            print("Failed")
app = GUI()
app.mainloop()
```

Comment: try `if self.pass_entry.get() == 'hello': ...` as `self.pass_entry` will never equal `'hello'` (the former is a tkinter widget -- the latter is a string).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does not work because you need to use the following to get the value of the password entered:

```
self.pass_entry.get()
```

Consequently, you should have:

```
if self.entry.get() and self.pass_entry.get() == "hello":
```

As a side note. If you have password Entry widget, better to do it as follows:

```
self.pass_entry = tk.Entry(self, show="*")
```

Comment: Ah haha, thankyou so much! Didn't realise I hadn't even added the get function!

Comment: I'm pretty sure the `if self.entry` check isn't doing anything.  a `tkinter.Widget` is likely to be truthy by default.

Comment: @mgilson you right. It also should be `self.entry.get()`:-)